# Check if a file has been properly transmitted via FTP

Tags: ftp, synchronization

This script will send a file via FTP and then delete it. But, sometimes, the file is deleted before the transmission ends, and then an empty file is received.

```
#!/bin/bash

tar czf <sourcefile> --directory=<directory> log
ftp -v -n $1 <<END_OF_SESSION
user <user> <password>
put <sourcefile> <targetfile>
bye
END_OF_SESSION

rm <sourcefile>
```

What would be a good way to synchronize the processes, such that the deletion occurs after the sending has completed?

As shown in the update below, the connection sometimes cannot be establish.

Notes:

Running on Lubuntu 16.04.

Updated with the `tar` line.

log information for a failed session:

```
Connected to IP
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
200 Switching to Binary mode.
local: /home/user01/tmp/log.tgz remote: E1/180418090056
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
425 Failed to establish connection.
221 Goodbye.
```

and a successful one:

```
Connected to IP
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
200 Switching to Binary mode.
local: /home/user01/tmp/log.tgz remote: E1/180418090344
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Ok to send data.
226 Transfer complete.
6901 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (43.5848 MB/s)
221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: is your ftp server working on windows ?

Comment: The script you've shown us will finish the ftp session before the rm is executed.

Comment: @Kiwy updated: Linux.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That's what I thought, but it's the only possible explanation I have to the 0-byte files received on the server.

Comment: Don't you want to change into `binary` mode before transfer?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Seems to be working fine like this, but yes, it should be explicitly done.

Comment: In general: in your scripts check the exit code of commands and include error handling. You currently don't know if the `ftp` command was completed successfully or not before you delete the source file. - Second calculate a checksum, store that in a second file and upload both to determine if what has been uploaded  differs from the original

Comment: Since you're giving ftp the `-v` option, it will print out everything it's doing. Can you paste a session where it transfers 0 bytes?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick question updated with the log info.

Comment: How frequently does this script run? There are several factors that can impact how quickly you can create a new TCP connection. As the warning message said, using passive mode may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ftp` command has no functionality to allow you to check for successful transfer. If you must continue using this implementation of FTP transfer, two alternatives are:

1. Download the transmitted file to a local temporary and compare it byte for byte against the source.
2. Run `ls` within the FTP client and check that the file length matches expectations. Bear in mind that `ls` is server dependent, and can vary from server implementation to implementation.

The best solution (other than replacing FTP entirely with `rsync` or `scp`) is to use a different FTP client that provides a reliable transfer status.

```
#!/bin/bash
tar czf <sourcefile> --directory=<directory> log
lftp -u '<user>,<password>' -e 'put -E <source> -o <target>; quit' "$1"
```

The `lftp` command should be available in most Linux distributions. The `-E` flag configures the `put` command to act more like `mv` rather than `cp`: it deletes the source file after a successful transfer.